# How to write code in F# for what functors do in OCaml?

Tags: f#, ocaml, functor

I have many programs written in OCaml, some of them use functors. Now, I am considering of writing and re-writing a part of code in F# (to benefit some advantages that OCaml does not have). One thing I am afraid of is to write code in F# for what functors do in OCaml.

For instance, how could we emulate [this example from OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html) in F#?

```
type comparison = Less | Equal | Greater

module type ORDERED_TYPE = sig
  type t
  val compare: t -> t -> comparison
end

module Set =
functor (Elt: ORDERED_TYPE) -> struct
    type element = Elt.t
    type set = element list
    let empty = []
    let rec add x s =
      match s with
        [] -> [x]
      | hd::tl ->
         match Elt.compare x hd with
           Equal   -> s         (* x is already in s *)
         | Less    -> x :: s    (* x is smaller than all elements of s *)
         | Greater -> hd :: add x tl
  end

module OrderedString = struct
  type t = string
  let compare x y = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater
end

module OrderedInt = struct
  type t = int
  let compare x y = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater
end

module StringSet = Set(OrderedString)
module IntSet = Set(OrderedInt)

let try1 () = StringSet.add "foo" StringSet.empty
let try2 () = IntSet.add 2 IntSet.empty
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noticed, F# doesn't have functors - F# modules cannot be parameterized by types. You can get similar results in F# using the object oriented parts of the language - interfaces, generic classes and inheritance.

Here's a heavy handed approach at emulating your example.

```
type Comparison = Less | Equal | Greater

/// Interface corresponding to ORDERED_TYPE signature
type IOrderedType<'a> = 
    abstract Value: 'a
    abstract Compare: IOrderedType<'a> -> Comparison

/// Type that implements ORDERED_TYPE signature, different instantiations
/// of this type correspond to your OrderedInt/OrderedString modules.
/// The 't: comparison constraint comes from the fact that (<) operator 
/// is used in the body of Compare.
type Ordered<'t when 't: comparison> (t: 't) =
    interface IOrderedType<'t> with
        member this.Value = t
        member this.Compare (other: IOrderedType<'t>) = 
            if t = other.Value then Equal else if t < other.Value then Less else Greater

/// A generic type that works over instances of IOrderedType interface.
type Set<'t, 'ot when 't: comparison and 'ot :> IOrderedType<'t>> (coll: IOrderedType<'t> list) =

    member this.Values = 
        coll |> List.map (fun x -> x.Value)

    member this.Add(x: 't) = 
        let rec add (x: IOrderedType<'t>) s = 
            match coll with
            | [] -> [x]
            | hd::tl ->
                match x.Compare(hd) with
                | Equal   -> s         (* x is already in s *)
                | Less    -> x :: s    (* x is smaller than all elements of s *)
                | Greater -> hd :: add x tl
        Set<'t, 'ot>(add (Ordered(x)) coll)

    static member Empty = Set<'t, 'ot>(List.empty)

/// A helper function for Set.Add. Useful in pipelines. 
module Set =     
    let add x (s: Set<_,_>) =
       s.Add(x)

/// Type aliases for different instantiations of Set 
/// (these could have easily been subtypes of Set as well)
type StringSet = Set<string, Ordered<string>>
type IntSet = Set<int, Ordered<int>>

let try1 () = Set.add "foo" StringSet.Empty
let try2 () = Set.add 2 IntSet.Empty

try1().Values
try2().Values
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer... When you say "heavy handed approach", you mean people in practice would not code like this?

Comment: @SoftTimur: Sort of - I tried not to diverge far from the original code, and it didn't feel natural to me by the time I got through the `Set` type. It's not far off, but I might have ended up with something different if I started from a clean sheet.

Comment: @SoftTimur: maybe that's just the convoluted type parameters on `Set`.

Comment: OK... let me ask in another way... If we assume functors are quite natural and common in OCaml, is this combination of interfaces + generic classes + inheritance natural in F#? or people in practice code in some alternative ways in F# to achieve similar things?

Comment: @SoftTimur: In general - yes, that's a natural way of doing type abstraction.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a bit different approach that achieves same outcome using a generic class and one object per type.

```
type Comparison = Less | Equal | Greater

type Set<'a>(compare : 'a -> 'a -> Comparison) =

    member this.Empty : 'a list = []

    member this.Add x s = 
         match s with
         | [] -> [x]
         | hd::tl ->
             match compare x hd with
             | Equal   -> s         (* x is already in s *)
             | Less    -> x :: s    (* x is smaller than all elements of s *)
             | Greater -> hd :: this.Add x tl


let compare x y = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater

let compareFloats (x : float) (y : float) = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater

// Note that same generic compare function can be used for stringSet and intSet
// as long as the type parameter is explicitly given
let stringSet = Set<string>(compare)
let intSet = Set<int>(compare)

// Type parameter not needed, because compareFloats is not generic
let floatSet = Set(compareFloats)

let try1 () = stringSet.Add "foo" stringSet.Empty   // -> ["foo"]
let try2 () = intSet.Add 2 intSet.Empty             // -> [2]
let try3 () = floatSet.Add 3.0 floatSet.Empty       // -> [3.0]
```

Comment: That's what I meant when I called my solution heavy-handed and not feeling natural.

Comment: Would I be totally off, if I mentioned https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx, and added silently and carefully: Why write code when solution are available? ;-) (Yes I do understand the benefit of learning by doing...)

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm The question was how to port OCaml code that uses functors to F#, not how to implement sorted set. I hope that this example helps to figure out how to port real world cases to F#.

Comment: @hvester Yes, I do understand that, and your answer was quite good. But I can not free myself from thinking that when porting use whatever environment your porting to. I think it just might be me, and not code, answer or otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

The functional way in F# would rely mostly on type inference avoiding OOP structures like `interface` or types with `member`.

```
type Comparison = Less | Equal | Greater
type OrderedSet<'t> = 't list     // type alias, not really necessary

module OrderedSet =
    let empty                      : OrderedSet<_> = List.empty  // just an empty list
    let values (s : OrderedSet<_>) : OrderedSet<_> = s           // identity function
    let add compare x (s : OrderedSet<_>)  : OrderedSet<_> =
        let rec addR s =
            match s with
            | [] -> [x]
            | hd::tl ->
                match compare x hd with
                | Equal   -> s         (* x is already in s *)
                | Less    -> x :: s    (* x is smaller than all elements of s *)
                | Greater -> hd :: addR tl
        addR s

    let compare        x          y = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater
    let compareFloats (x : float) y = if x = y then Equal else if x < y then Less else Greater

    let addGeneric v = add compare       v
    let addFloat   v = add compareFloats v
```

And it is used like this:

```
let try1 () = OrderedSet.addGeneric "foo" OrderedSet.empty |> OrderedSet.addGeneric "bar"
let try2 () = OrderedSet.addGeneric 2     OrderedSet.empty |> OrderedSet.addGeneric 3 
let try3 () = OrderedSet.empty 
              |> OrderedSet.addFloat 3.0 
              |> OrderedSet.addFloat 1.0 
              |> OrderedSet.addFloat 2.0

try1() |> printfn "%A"  // OrderedSet<string> = ["bar"; "foo"]  
try2() |> printfn "%A"  // OrderedSet<int>    = [2; 3]
try3() |> printfn "%A"  // OrderedSet<float>  = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
```

The type alias `type OrderedSet<'t> = 't list` and the functions `empty` and `values` are not really necessary but they help to mask the actual implementation (in case that is desirable).