# Implementing Standard ML signatures in F# / .NET

Tags: .net, types, f#, sml, translate

**(Questions are at the bottom in bold.)**

I'm going through [Chris Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) and I was attempting to translate the first data structure and its implementations from Standard ML to F#. The ML is as follows (translated from the book):

```ml
signature STACK =
sig
    type 'a Stack
    val empty : 'a Stack
    val isEmpty : 'a Stack -> bool
    val cons : 'a * 'a Stack -> 'a Stack
    val head : 'a Stack -> 'a (* raises EMPTY if stack is empty *)
    val tail : 'a Stack -> 'a Stack (* raises EMPTY if stack is empty *)
end
```

and its first implementation:

```ml
structure List:STACK =
struct
    type 'a Stack = 'a list

    val empty = []
    fun isEmpty s = null s

    fun cons (x,s) = x :: s
    fun head s = hd s
    fun tail s = tl s
end
```

and, for clarity, its second implementation:

```ml
structure CustomStack:STACK =
struct 
    datatype 'a Stack = NIL | CONS of 'a * 'a Stack

    val empty = NIL
    fun isEmpty NIL = true | isEmpty _ = false

    fun cons (x, s) = CONS(x, s)
    fun head NIL = raise EMPTY
      | head (CONS(x, s)) = x
    fun tail NIL = raise EMPTY
      | tail (CONS(x, s)) = s
end
```

---

I was able to port the ML `signature` to F# almost term for term:

```
type 'a Stack = Stack of 'a

type 'a STACK =
    val Stack : 'a Stack
    val empty : 'a Stack

    val isEmpty : 'a Stack -> bool
    val cons : 'a * 'a Stack -> 'a Stack
    val head : 'a Stack -> 'a
    val tail : 'a Stack -> 'a Stack
```

This code compiles even though, somewhat obviously, there is no way to implement the F# type as anything substantial, as there is no constructor and it is *not* recognized as an interface (and can't be written as one because `val Stack` and `val empty` are not functions). It compiles in `fsi` as a class, but obviously no constructor or anything to implement it. The `fsi` signature of the previous snippet is:

```
type 'a Stack = | Stack of 'a
type 'a STACK =
  class
    val Stack: 'a Stack
    val empty: 'a Stack
    val isEmpty: 'a Stack -> bool
    val cons: 'a * 'a Stack -> 'a Stack
    val head: 'a Stack -> 'a
    val tail: 'a Stack -> 'a Stack
  end
```

**1. Is there any way to make use of this in the .NET ecosystem, to have just a pure type like this, practical or not? Also, is this considered some sort of bug to be able to create a non-implementable datatype?**

**2. Is there anyway to implement the Standard ML datastructures in F# without using interfaces and abstract classes, or are they mandatory because of the way .NET is structured?**

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but two things: 1) It's not really a coincidence that you could port the ML signature to F# almost term for term, because F#'s syntax was taken from ML (from OCaml, I think). 2) You might be interested in looking at the source for https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections to see what's been implemented already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Is there any way to make use of this in the .NET ecosystem, to have just a pure type like this, practical or not? Also, is this considered some sort of bug to be able to create a non-implementable datatype?**

What you have implemented compiles, but it's most certainly not what you intended to implement. It's only syntactically similar - what you're using is something called [explicit class syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/explicit-fields-the-val-keyword), and your `STACK` type is a class ostensibly without a public constructor with a bunch of getter-only properties.

This is something you can check yourself through the reflection API. If you're using this code in FSI, you may find that a constructor is generated for that type anyway, and you can use `Activator.Create` to instantiate it - you'll see the properties all having the default null values.

```
open System
open System.Reflection

let typ = typeof<STACK<int>>

typ.GetProperties()

let stack = Activator.CreateInstance<STACK<int>>()
```

That's an artifact of FSI usage afaik, in compiled code you'd have no way of constructing a value of this type.

**2. Is there anyway to implement the Standard ML datastructures in F# without using interfaces and abstract classes, or are they mandatory because of the way .NET is structured?**

As far as translating the concepts goes, abstract classes and their subtypes are the most direct F# equivalent of SML signatures and structures.

This has to do with F# eschewing OCaml module system (with signatures, structures and functors) in favor of the OOP system already present .NET intermediate language. F# modules are severely limited in comparison, they're more of a grouping/namespacing tool similar to what Haskell has.

Not sure about what your experience is - I know newcomers to the language that come from an OOP background are often eager to completely abandon classes, interfaces and anything they associate with OOP, but that's a rather misguided approach. There's a reason why those concepts are part of F#, and by not using them, you're giving up a significant part of your ability to express things.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847449/how-to-write-code-in-f-for-what-functors-do-in-ocaml) for a similar example of an ML to F# "translation". Note that this is more "toy example" level than "solid library code" level - for that it would be advisable to use the entrenched .NET collection interfaces so that it meshes well with the wider ecosystem. This is what `FSharp.Core` collections do for example.